# Why doesn't my program work when I deploy it to my vercel website, but it works on the local flask server on my PC?

Tags: javascript, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am using flask-socketio to transfer information between my python and javascript file.

Below is the snippet of code that I was using in the JS file that worked on my PC to connect to the socket.

const socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

I am aware that since the vercel website is an https domain, I cannot use http to connect my websocket, but when I replace the "http" with "https" in the io.connect line, it still does not work, and I get 400 and 504 errors. I also tried const socket = io();, but that didn't work either. I'm very new to socketio, so I am unsure about what I am doing wrong.

Error messages:

GET mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling 400 (Bad Request) POST mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling 400 (Bad Request) WebSocket connection to '' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established. GET mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling 504 (Gateway Timeout) POST mywebsite.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling 504 (Gateway Timeout)

Comment: @SarthakDwivedi That didn't work.

Comment: Vercel only hosts serverless functions, so you can't run a whole flask instance on a vercel server. https://vercel.com/guides/do-vercel-serverless-functions-support-websocket-connections

Comment: @Kokodoko What do you recommend I use to send my python variables to my javascript file?

Comment: You need a hosting provider that allows you to run flask on their server. It's not so common to get this for free though, you'll have to google.

Comment: The other option is to convert your python script to serverless javascript functions, to make it run on Vercel :)

Comment: Look at the server logs for clues. Also see the Flask-SocketIO documentation section on troubleshooting to learn how to generate more verbose logging that might help.